# "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present" in Spring Data Redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I have a test, where Spring Data Redis is used.

This is the configuration:

```
public class StartUpConfiguration {

@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new
            RedisStandaloneConfiguration("redis server", 6379);
    //redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of("yourRedisPasswordIfAny"));
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
}

@Bean
RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return redisTemplate;
}
}
```

This is the repository

```
    @Repository
public interface repo extends CrudRepository<repoRedisEntity, String> {
}
```

This is the entity

```
    @AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@RedisHash(value = "Quote", timeToLive = 3600)
public class RedisEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private final String id;
    private Double price;
}
```

And this is the test

```
RedisEntity retrievedEntity = quoteRedisRepository.findById(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).get();
    retrievedQuoteRedisEntity.setPrice(10 * item / 100);
    quoteRedisRepository.save(retrievedQuoteRedisEntity);
```

For some reason I am receiving.

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
```

Comment: The error is reported because you don’t have a value with key `UUID.randomUUID()`, which seems logical because you have not created any entry. The `randomUUID` will return a random number, so the `findById` is “guaranteed” to return empty.

Comment: The return value of `findById` is an optional. If you invoke `get` on an empty optional, you will get a `NoSuchElementException`. No surprises there.